# Mex binaries not loaded

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use this software available at http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~aspremon/ZIP/COVSEL.zip. They have a function spmlcdvec defined in a matlab file spmlcdvec.m. It further calls a function BoxQP for which they have provided a binary mex file called BoxQP.mexmac. However, when I run the  function spmlcdvec it says

```
Undefined function 'BoxQP' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What should I do? Whats going wrong?

Comment: check if the mex file is on your path when you perform that call. That error usually means the function isn't visible

Answer (score 3):

Run [`mexext`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexext.html) in your command window. If it does not return `mexmac` (or `mexw32` which is also present in the folder) then you you won't be able to run the `BoxQP` function. These are simply old files - I see that they're from 2006. If you're using any form of OS X these days you'll get [`mexmaci64`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-mex-files-to-call-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html#bra56dy-1), which is not compatible. However, it looks like they have helpfully included all of the source code so you'll be able to hopefully compile the binaries for your system. For details on compiling [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) code [see this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html).

Then, as @alrikai suggests, your `BoxQP` function needs to be on your path. Either make sure that you call your code from the same folder or run [`path`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) from the command window and check if that directory has been properly added (if you did so). See also [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html).